# Numpy extract row, column and value from a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a matrix, and I want to write a script to extract values which are bigger than zero, its row number and column number(because the value belongs to that (row, column)), and here's an example,

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np

m=np.array([[0,2,4],[4,0,4],[5,4,0]])
index_row=[]
index_col=[]
dist=[]
```

I want to store the row number in **index_row**, the column number in **index_col**, and the value in **dist**. So in this case,

```
index_row = [0 0 1 1 2 2]
index_col = [1 2 0 2 0 1]
dist = [2 4 4 4 5 4]
```

How to add the codes to achieve this goal? Thanks for giving me suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this:

```
>>> indices = np.where(m > 0)
>>> index_row, index_col = indices
>>> dist = m[indices]
>>> index_row
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
>>> index_col
array([1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1])
>>> dist
array([2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4])
```

Comment: It will be slightly faster if you kept `mask = m > 1` around, and used it to retrieve the values as `dist = m[mask]`.

Answer (score 1):

Though this has been answered already, I often find `np.where` to be somewhat cumbersome-- though like all things, depends on the circumstance. For this, I'd probably use a [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
index_row = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
index_col = [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]
zipped = zip(index_row, index_col)
dist = [m[z] for z in zipped]
```

The `zip` will give you an iteratable of tuples, which can be used to index numpy arrays.